# -lmxml library not found in mini-xml?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, mini-xml

I've built and installed mini-xml already on my computer, but when I try to compile their test program with `gcc testmxml.c -lmxml -o myprogram`, the error `ld: library not found for -lmxml`

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: While inside the mxml-2.9 folder, `./configure` then `make` then `make install` @Wimmel

Answer (score 0):

Use the compiler option `-L<directory-with-lib-file>` to point to the directory (`<directory-with-lib-file>`) to where you build the `libmxml.so`, `libmxml.a` file(s).

Place this option on gcc's command line **before** the `-lmxml` option.

Example:

```
-L/the/path/to/the/library/ -lmxml
```

More details on how to steer gcc's linker may be read here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: How do I check the location of the lib file?

Comment: @MiguelLorenzoPanagsagan: Try `find / -name "libmxml.*"`

Comment: When I try it, it keeps on saying permission denied in all locations

Comment: This is what appears when I use `find / -name "libmxml.*" | less` 
./libmxml.1.dylib
./libmxml.a
./libmxml.dylib
(END)

Comment: So its just right before you eyes, that in the current work directory, the directory you use to call `find` from. Do a `ls -l libmxml.*`.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a beginner at coding too.
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 gracepanagsagan  staff   53340 May 17 17:44 libmxml.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 gracepanagsagan  staff  176096 May 17 17:44 libmxml.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 gracepanagsagan  staff      15 May 17 17:44 libmxml.dylib -> libmxml.1.dylib`

Comment: So you finally found the library `libmxml.a`. :-) Give a `pwd` and use the path return as argument to the `-L ` option

Comment: When I try `<Users/gracepanagsagan/downloads/mxml-2.9/libmxml.a>` or `<Users/gracepanagsagan/downloads/mxml-2.9>` it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: Give the directory without the `<>`. And **only** the directory. The library itself you specify using `-lmxml`: `-L/Users/gracepanagsagan/downloads/mxml-2.9 -lmxml`.

Comment: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LUsers/gracepanagsagan/downloads/mxml-2.9'
ld: library not found for -lmxml

Comment: Mind the leading slash `/`.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question you might like to accept the answer as such by clicking its check-mark. If you like the answer you also are free to upvote it.

Comment: Got another problem. Again, I try to compile my program in another folder. This time the error is `'mxml.h' file not found`

Comment: Use `-I<directory>` to specify the **directory** for addtional include files. You already just learned how to locate a certain file in the file system. Also this formally would have been another question ...